# Trouble with Eclipse and Android-x86 source code

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, android-x86

I'm trying to create an application directly into the Android source code, it uses libraries and drivers created by me for different layers of AOSP. I follow the steps in http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html and http://blog.simonstahl.com/2012/07/12/edit-the-core-android-source-code-in-eclipse.

1. For this I executed the command make ECLIPSE-lunch, so this creates the file .classpath in {Android source root}.
2. I turn off the automatic code compiling.
3. I create a new Java Project in Eclipse using as workspace the {Android source root}.
4. Then when I create a new Application Project in {Android source root}/devices/xxx/yyy/apps are some unresolved references. e.g. unresolved references to android.os.ServiceManager (included in the SDK) and R.layout.log_activity.

So, how can I work comfortably with a good code completion?

I have not idea of how to configure Eclipse to do it work fine! But I have correctly configured and added external sdk and ndk to it in Windows => Preferences => Android: SDK Location and NDK Location.

I'm using Nova 4.0 operating system (based on Ubuntu), my code includes Java files, AIDL files, XML files and C/C++ (JNI) files.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: will you add your application in AOSP build and it will be preinstalled with other system apps (Launcher, Settings, etc.)? If so, why are you compiling Eclipse sources? Need you custom ROM or need you custom Eclipse compiled from AOSP?